# Execute java class in zip by command line

Tags: java, command-line

If I create a jar file hello.jar then execute Hello class in hello.jar as follows,

```
java -cp hello.jar Hello
```

it works properly and execute main method of Hello class in jar file.

But if I create a zip file hello.zip then execute Hello class in hello.zip as follows,

```
java -cp hello.zip Hello
```

I got **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** Exception.

How can I execute java class in zip file by command line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put the MANIFEST.MF file inside your zip?

Answer (score 0):

As I am thinking you could use zip instead of jar, The problem might with Manifest file 
 check it http://eduunix.ccut.edu.cn/index2/html/java/Que.Special.Edition.Using.Java.2.Standard.Edition.internal.eBook-LiB/ch25lev1sec2.html